# What does 'mod' stand for in this ODE book?

Tags: group-theory, ordinary-differential-equations

I've seen in a book some:

mod(a)=b

What does it mean?

I've seen this in a book on solving ODE by using symmetries, but I am not sure about what it means.

Stephani's Differential Equations: Their Solution Using Symmetries.

He states H=0 a dif. eq. and applies to it an generator X (an differential operator) and requires that this new dif. eq. XH=0 has the same solution of the former (i.e., H=0).

"An ordinary differential equation:

$$H(x,y,y^{\prime},\dots,y^{(n)})=0$$

admits a group of symmetries with generator $\bf{X}$ if and only if

$$XH=0, \pmod {H =0},$$

holds".

By the way, if there's anybody there reading some book of this kind (just like Stephani's or Hydon's), please contact me. I'd be very glad on discussing and sharing some ideas.

Comment: Could it mean modulus (as in absolute value)?

Comment: @PoliTolstov: Welcome to MSE! What book did you see this in? Regards

Comment: Stephani's Differential Equations: Their Solution Using Symmetries.

Comment: He states H=0 a dif. eq. and applies to it an generator X (an differential operator) and requires that this new  dif. eq. XH=0 has the same solution of the former (i.e., H=0).

Comment: After that he writes : XH=0  (mod H=0). I don't understand this.

Comment: Are you sure this notation isn't defined in your book somewhere?

Comment: If you are referring to page 19 (first edition), the next paragraph gives some information...